# Access Enum value using EL with JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have an Enum called Status defined as such:

```
public enum Status { 

    VALID("valid"), OLD("old");

    private final String val;

    Status(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return val;
    }

}
```

I would like to access the value of `VALID` from a JSTL tag. Specifically the `test` attribute of the `<c:when>` tag. E.g.

```
<c:when test="${dp.status eq Status.VALID">
```

I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

A simple comparison against string works:

```xml
<c:when test="${someModel.status == 'OLD'}">
```

Comment: For those requiring a source: This is specified (for instance) in section 1.17 of the "Expression Language Specification, version 2.2",  which is part of [JSR-245](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245).

Comment: The JavaServer Pages™ Specification, Version 2.0 says in JSP.2.3.5.7: "• If A or B is String coerce both A and B to String, compare lexically"

Comment: But you loose the advantage of having an enum: this could lead to cumbersome misunderstandings if the enum gets changed one day. Usually, if I find myself changing an enum, I feel pretty safe, and probably I wouldn't remember that string-to-enum-reference in that view...

Comment: Right, it is better to place decision-making code out of the view. Yet sometimes one have to.

Comment: Is this comparing against the toString of the enum? So if you override the toString (e.g. you want a friendly display name), then you need to make sure you also change the value that is being matched against.

Comment: FWIW, today on my Java 8 (IBM Java for WebSphere, in case it matters), this doesn't seem to work. It seems to only work if comparing against the string value, which here would be lower case "old"

Answer (score 54):

If using Spring MVC, the Spring Expression Language (SpEL) can be helpful:

```xml
<spring:eval expression="dp.status == T(com.example.Status).VALID" var="isValid" />
<c:if test="${isValid}">
   isValid
</c:if>
```

Comment: Seems this doesn't work for inner enums?

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 0): Type cannot be found 'my.package.model.EngagementRequest.EngagementStatus'

Comment: Try to use 'my.package.model.EngagementRequest$EngagementStatus'

Comment: A good thing about this solution is that you get an error message if there is a mistake in your expression, which does not always happen with `<c:if>` and `<c:when>` (they fail quietly).

Answer (score 41):

You have 3 choices here, none of which is perfect:

1. You can use a scriptlet in the `test` attribute:

   `<c:when test="<%= dp.getStatus() == Status.VALID %>">`

   This uses the enum, but it also uses a scriptlet, which is not the "right way" in JSP 2.0. But most importantly, this doesn't work when you want to add another condition to the same `when` using `${}`. And this means all the variables you want to test have to be declared in a scriptlet, or kept in request, or session (`pageContext` variable is not available in `.tag` files).
2. You can compare against string:

   `<c:when test="${dp.status == 'VALID'}">`

   This looks clean, but you're introducing a string that duplicates the enum value and cannot be validated by the compiler. So if you remove that value from the enum or rename it, you will not see that this part of code is not accessible anymore. You basically have to do a search/replace through the code each time.
3. You can add each of the enum values you use into the page context:

   `<c:set var="VALID" value="<%=Status.VALID%>"/>`

   and then you can do this:

   `<c:when test="${dp.status == VALID}">`

I prefer the last option (3), even though it also uses a scriptlet. This is because it only uses it when you set the value. Later on you can use it in more complex EL expressions, together with other EL conditions. While in option (1) you cannot use a scriptlet and an EL expression in the `test` attribute of a single `when` tag.

Comment: Regarding option 2, the compiler can not verify it, but at runtime the string will be converted into an enum using `Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` which will trigger an `ELException` if the enum has no constant with that name. The expression will not just always be false.

Answer (score 23):

So to get my problem fully resolved I needed to do the following:

```xml
<% pageContext.setAttribute("old", Status.OLD); %>
```

Then I was able to do:

```xml
<c:when test="${someModel.status == old}"/>...</c:when>
```

which worked as expected.

Comment: using scriptlets is bad style.

Answer (score 16):

Here are two more possibilities:

## JSP EL 3.0 Constants

As long as you are using at least version 3.0 of EL, then you can import constants into your page as follows:

```
<%@ page import="org.example.Status" %>
<c:when test="${dp.status eq Status.VALID}">
```

However, some IDEs don't understand this yet (e.g. [IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138230)) so you won't get any warnings if you make a typo, until runtime.

This would be my preferred method once it gets proper IDE support.

## Helper Methods

You could just add getters to your enum.

```
public enum Status { 
  VALID("valid"), OLD("old");

  private final String val;

  Status(String val) {
    this.val = val;
  }

  public String getStatus() {
    return val;
  }

  public boolean isValid() {
    return this == VALID;
  }

  public boolean isOld() {
    return this == OLD;
  }
}
```

Then in your JSP:

```
<c:when test="${dp.status.valid}">
```

This is supported in all IDEs and will also work if you can't use EL 3.0 yet. This is what I do at the moment because it keeps all the logic wrapped up into my enum.

Also be careful if it is possible for the variable storing the enum to be null. You would need to check for that first if your code doesn't guarantee that it is not null:

```
<c:when test="${not empty db.status and dp.status.valid}">
```

I think this method is superior to those where you set an intermediary value in the JSP because you have to do that on each page where you need to use the enum. However, with this solution you only need to declare the getter once.

Comment: "JSP EL 3.0 Constants" part must be the accepted answer since it's the standard way to achieve the required result using built-in functionality. On a side note, InteliJ IDEA (at least Ultimate version 2017.2.4) does support it out of the box and shows list of available constants when you type `${MyEnum.}`, put caret right after dot and press `Ctrl+Space` to show suggestions.

Comment: [**UPDATE**] Seems like IntelliJ IDEA already fixed the issue mentioned in this answer.

Comment: I appreciate this is a few years later, but thought I'd add a comment as it may help others. EL 3.0 doesn't pick up a Java enum if it is stored within another class. E.g. this works:

`public enum TestEnum {
 AWAITING,
 FILE_PRESENT,
 FILE_NOT_FOUND;
}`

but this doesn't:

`public class TestClass {
 
 public enum TestEnum {
     AWAITING,
     FILE_PRESENT,
          FILE_NOT_FOUND;
 }
}`

Which is very frustrating as I never dedicate a whole class file to an enum!

Answer (score 10):

For this purposes I do the following:

```xml
<c:set var="abc">
    <%=Status.OLD.getStatus()%>
</c:set>

<c:if test="${someVariable == abc}">
    ....
</c:if>
```

It's looks ugly, but works!

Answer (score 3):

I do not have an answer to the question of Kornel, but I've a remark about the other script examples. Most of the expression trust implicitly on the `toString()`, but the `Enum.valueOf()` expects a value that comes from/matches the `Enum.name()` property. So one should use e.g.:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("Status_OLD", Status.OLD.name()); %>
...
<c:when test="${someModel.status == Status_OLD}"/>...</c:when>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to the enum like:

```
public String getString() {
    return this.name();
}
```

For example

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2;
    public String getString() {
        return this.name();
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
<c:if test="${myObject.myEnumProperty.string eq 'VALUE_2'}">...</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a MVC framework I put the following in my controller.

```
request.setAttribute(RequestParameterNamesEnum.INBOX_ACTION.name(), RequestParameterNamesEnum.INBOX_ACTION.name());
```

This allows me to use the following in my JSP Page.

```
<script> var url = 'http://www.nowhere.com/?${INBOX_ACTION}=' + someValue;</script>
```

It can also be used in your comparison

```
<c:when test="${someModel.action == INBOX_ACTION}">
```

Which I prefer over putting in a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ page import="com.example.Status" %>

1. ${dp.status eq Title.VALID.getStatus()}
2. ${dp.status eq Title.VALID}
3. ${dp.status eq Title.VALID.toString()}
```

- Put the import at the **top**, in JSP page header
- If you want to work with **getStatus method**, use **#1**
- If you want to work with the **enum element** itself, use either **#2 or #3**
- You can use **==** instead of **eq**

Answer (score -1):

I generally consider it bad practice to mix java code into jsps/tag files. Using 'eq' should do the trick :

```
<c:if test="${dp.Status eq 'OLD'}">
  ...
</c:if>
```

Comment: So it is a bad practice to use `==` instead of `eq` ? They do both exactly the same, so there's no means of a "trick".

Comment: Of course, I wasn't making a statement regarding the use of eq vs ==. Many answers to this question involved inserting java code into jsp or tag files which can be a crutch. I favor keeping business logic in java code (where it can be unit tested easily and thoroughly) separate from display logic in the JSP.

Comment: To me it seems an equally bad practice to insert magic strings into your JSP which can't be checked by the compiler when you want to refactor your enums. Seems like there's no good solution to this on either side.

Answer (score -1):

I do it this way when there are many points to use...

```
public enum Status { 

    VALID("valid"), OLD("old");

    private final String val;

    Status(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return val;
    }

    public static void setRequestAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String,String> vals = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (Status val : Status.values()) {
            vals.put(val.name(), val.value);
        }
        request.setAttribute("Status", vals);
    }

}
```

JSP

```
<%@ page import="...Status" %>
<% Status.setRequestAttributes(request) %>

<c:when test="${dp.status eq Status.VALID}">
...
```

Answer (score -2):

**In Java Class:**

```
    public class EnumTest{
    //Other property link
    private String name;
    ....

        public enum Status {
                ACTIVE,NEWLINK, BROADCASTED, PENDING, CLICKED, VERIFIED, AWARDED, INACTIVE, EXPIRED, DELETED_BY_ADMIN;
            }

        private Status statusobj ;

    //Getter and Setters
}
```

So now POJO and enum obj is created. 
Now **EnumTest** you will set in session object using in the servlet or controller class
session.setAttribute("enumTest", EnumTest );

**In JSP Page**

```
<c:if test="${enumTest.statusobj == 'ACTIVE'}">

//TRUE??? THEN PROCESS SOME LOGIC
```