# How to reference constants in EL?

Tags: jsp, constants, el

How do you reference an constants with EL on a JSP page?

I have an interface `Addresses` with a constant named `URL`. I know I can reference it with a scriplet by going: `<%=Addresses.URL%>`, but how do I do this using EL?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

## EL 3.0 or newer

If you're already on Java EE 7 / EL 3.0, then the `@page import` will also import class constants in EL scope.

```
<%@ page import="com.example.YourConstants" %>
```

This will under the covers be imported via [`ImportHandler#importClass()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/el/ImportHandler.html#importClass-java.lang.String-) and be available as `${YourConstants.FOO}`.

Note that all `java.lang.*` classes are already implicitly imported and available like so `${Boolean.TRUE}` and `${Integer.MAX_VALUE}`. This only requires a more recent Java EE 7 container server as early versions had bugs in this. E.g. GlassFish 4.0 and Tomcat 8.0.0-1x fails, but GlassFish 4.1+ and Tomcat 8.0.2x+ works. And you need to make absolutely sure that your `web.xml` is declared conform the latest servlet version supported by the server. Thus with a `web.xml` which is declared conform Servlet 2.5 or older, none of the Servlet 3.0+ features will work.

Also note that this facility is only available in JSP and not in Facelets. In case of JSF+Facelets, your best bet is using [OmniFaces `<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants) as below:

```html
<o:importConstants type="com.example.YourConstants" />
```

Or adding an EL context listener which calls `ImportHandler#importClass()` as below:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Config {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().addELContextListener(new ELContextListener() {
            @Override
            public void contextCreated(ELContextEvent event) {
                event.getELContext().getImportHandler().importClass("com.example.YourConstants");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

---

## EL 2.2 or older

This is **not** possible in EL 2.2 and older. There are several alternatives:

1. Put them in a `Map<String, Object>` which you put in the application scope. In EL, map values are accessible the usual Javabean way by `${map.key}` or `${map['key.with.dots']}`.
2. Use `<un:useConstants>` of the *Unstandard* taglib (maven2 repo [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/taglibs-unstandard/20060829)):

   ```html
   <%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/unstandard-1.0" prefix="un" %>
   <un:useConstants className="com.example.YourConstants" var="constants" />
   ```

   This way they are accessible the usual Javabean way by `${constants.FOO}`.
3. Use Javaranch's [CCC](https://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/ccc.jar) `<ccc:constantsMap>` as desribed somewhere at the bottom of [this article](https://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/Journal200601.jsp#a3).

   ```html
   <%@ taglib uri="http://bibeault.org/tld/ccc" prefix="ccc" %>
   <ccc:constantsMap className="com.example.YourConstants" var="constants" />
   ```

   This way they are accessible the usual Javabean way by `${constants.FOO}` as well.
4. If you're using JSF2, then you could use [`<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants) of [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org).

   ```html
   <html ... xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
   <o:importConstants type="com.example.YourConstants" />
   ```

   This way they are accessible the usual Javabean way by `#{YourConstants.FOO}` as well.
5. Create a wrapper class which returns them through Javabean-style getter methods.
6. Create a custom EL resolver which first scans the presence of a constant and if absent, then delegate to the default resolver, otherwise returns the constant value instead.

Comment: I found this question because I was having the same problem when trying to use a static List field with a form:options tag.  I was able to get it working by adding a non-static getter that returns the static list.  It's a little kludgy but hey, that's JSP development for ya!

Comment: Do you have any example how to configure this for JSF if the beans are managed by spring? Thx in advance.

Comment: @Lodger: I don't do Spring.

Comment: Is the jakarta `unstandard-taglib` project still alive? is there some alternative?

Comment: Is there a way to leverage this techniques for enums?

Comment: @Niklas: enums are also constants.

Comment: @BalusC Yesterday I tried it with enum ````MyEnum```` and inserted ````<@page import="myPackage.MyEnum" %>````. Then ````${MyEnum.MEMBER}```` still returned empty string, whereas importing constants works. I use Tomcat 8.0.28 and Java 8. With scriptlets of course it does work ...

Comment: Concerning the EL 3.0 JSF variant, a bug was submitted for Mojarra 2.2+ and fixed for future version Mojarra 2.3: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-4189 - This bug prevents class/constants resolution in JSTL tags like <c:if test="#{val eq MyEnum.CONST}"/>

Comment: If I open a bounty on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44518143/getting-variable-in-jsp-el-by-constant-does-not-work can you help to solve the problem?

Comment: Note that this only works for concrete classes.  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ImportHandler.html states that the class must not be abstract or an interface.  This appears to be more of a stylistic assertion than a technical limitation, but reference implementations enforce it.

Comment: I'm not seeing this working. I have a class with constants I'm trying to reference. I.e. `MyClass.MY_CONST`. The value of `MY_CONST` in this case is an array of the enum values, i.e. `public static final MyEnum[] MY_CONST = { MyEnum.VAL1, MyEnum.VAL2}`

Comment: @Ryan: You're referring to the EL 3.0 approach? That can happen when your server or web.xml is not EL 3.0 compatible.

Comment: @BalusC, yes, I am talking about the EL 3.0 methodology. I'm using Wildfly 12 at the moment.

Answer (score 11):

The following does not apply to EL in general, but instead to SpEL (Spring EL) only (tested with 3.2.2.RELEASE on Tomcat 7).
I think it is worth mentioning it here in case someone searches for JSP and EL (but uses JSP with Spring).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<spring:eval var="constant" expression="T(com.example.Constants).CONSTANT"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

You usually place these kinds of constants in a `Configuration` object (which has getters and setters) in the servlet context, and access them with `${applicationScope.config.url}`

Comment: Bit of a novice here when it comes to jsp's- could you explain that more fully?

Comment: @tau-neutrino: Its simple actually. Create a class with `url` as a String property, name it `Configuration`, instantiate it and set the `url` to whatever you like. After that set that `Configuration` object in `ServletContext`. Do something like, `servletContext.setAttribute("config", config)`. And there you go.

Comment: What's the difference between your proposed solution and simply adding the constant as an attribute of the `ServletContext`? Is it just that you can classify the constants more neatly? eg: `applicationScope.config.url` vs `applicationScope.url`.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. It follows the Java Bean convention. So you must have a getter for it.

Answer (score 5):

Static properties aren't accessible in EL. The workaround I use is to create a non-static variable which assigns itself to the static value.

```
public final static String MANAGER_ROLE = 'manager';
public String manager_role = MANAGER_ROLE;
```

I use lombok to generate the getter and setter so that's pretty well it. Your EL looks like this:

```
${bean.manager_role}
```

Full code at https://rogerkeays.com/access-java-static-methods-and-constants-from-el

Answer (score 5):

I implemented like:

```
public interface Constants{
    Integer PAGE_SIZE = 20;
}
```

-

```
public class JspConstants extends HashMap<String, String> {

        public JspConstants() {
            Class c = Constants.class;
            Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
            for(Field field : fields) {
                int modifier = field.getModifiers();
                if(Modifier.isPublic(modifier) && Modifier.isStatic(modifier) && Modifier.isFinal(modifier)) {
                    try {
                        Object o = field.get(null);
                        put(field.getName(), o != null ? o.toString() : null);
                    } catch(IllegalAccessException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String get(Object key) {
            String result = super.get(key);
            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Check key! The key is wrong, no such constant!");
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Next step put instance of this class into servlerContext

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements ServletContextListener {


    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("Constants", new JspConstants());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

add listener to web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.ApplicationInitializer</listener-class>
</listener>
```

access in jsp

```
${Constants.PAGE_SIZE}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm defining a constant in my jsp right at the beginning:

```
<%final String URI = "http://www.example.com/";%>
```

I include the core taglib in my JSP:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Then, I make the constant available to EL by following statement:

```
<c:set var="URI" value="<%=URI%>"></c:set>
```

Now, I can use it later. Here an example, where the value is just written as HTML comment for debugging purposes:

```
<!-- ${URI} -->
```

---

With your constant class, you can just import your class and assign the constants to local variables. I know that my answer is a sort of quick hack, but the question also bumps up when one wants to define constants directly in the JSP.

Comment: lol why not use Scriptlets directly if that's how you initialize the EL variables?

Comment: Three lines on the top being a mess and then clean EL throughout the rest of the JSP ^^.

Comment: @koppoor I guess so. I'm just going to use `<%=URI%>` :P

Comment: I had a place where a direct `<%=URI%>` did not work, but this technique did.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You need a custom tag (if you can't find it somewhere else). I've done this:

```
package something;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport;

import org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ExpressionUtil;

/**
 * Get all class constants (statics) and place into Map so they can be accessed
 * from EL.
 * @author Tim.sabin
 */
public class ConstMapTag extends TagSupport {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 0x2ed23c0f306L;

    private String path = "";
    private String var = "";

    public void setPath (String path) throws JspException {
        this.path = (String)ExpressionUtil.evalNotNull ("constMap", "path",
          path, String.class, this, pageContext);
    }

    public void setVar (String var) throws JspException {
        this.var = (String)ExpressionUtil.evalNotNull ("constMap", "var",
          var, String.class, this, pageContext);
    }

    public int doStartTag () throws JspException {
        // Use Reflection to look up the desired field.
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = null;
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName (path);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                throw new JspException ("Class " + path + " not found.");
            }
            Field [] flds = clazz.getDeclaredFields ();
            // Go through all the fields, and put static ones in a Map.
            Map<String, Object> constMap = new TreeMap<String, Object> ();
            for (int i = 0; i < flds.length; i++) {
                // Check to see if this is public static final. If not, it's not a constant.
                int mods = flds [i].getModifiers ();
                if (!Modifier.isFinal (mods) || !Modifier.isStatic (mods) ||
                  !Modifier.isPublic (mods)) {
                    continue;
                }
                Object val = null;
                try {
                    val = flds [i].get (null);    // null for static fields.
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println ("Problem getting value of " + flds [i].getName ());
                    continue;
                }
                // flds [i].get () automatically wraps primitives.
                // Place the constant into the Map.
                constMap.put (flds [i].getName (), val);
            }
            // Export the Map as a Page variable.
            pageContext.setAttribute (var, constMap);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (!(ex instanceof JspException)) {
                throw new JspException ("Could not process constants from class " + path);
            } else {
                throw (JspException)ex;
            }
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
}
```

and the tag is called:

```
<yourLib:constMap path="path.to.your.constantClass" var="consts" />
```

All public static final variables will be put into a Map indexed by their Java name, so if

```
public static final int MY_FIFTEEN = 15;
```

then the tag will wrap this in an Integer and you can reference it in a JSP:

```
<c:if test="${consts['MY_FIFTEEN'] eq 15}">
```

and you don't have to write getters!

Answer (score 3):

You can. Try in follow way

```
 #{T(com.example.Addresses).URL}
```

Tested on TomCat 7 and java6

Comment: That looks like SpEL, and not EL. Am I mistaken? Also, would that work in an older Tomcat5.5?

Answer (score 2):

Even knowing its a little late, and even knowing this is a little hack - i used the following solution to achieve the desired result. If you are a lover of Java-Naming-Conventions, my advice is to stop reading here...

Having a class like this, defining Constants, grouped by empty classes to create kind of a hierarchy:

```
public class PERMISSION{
    public static class PAGE{
       public static final Long SEE = 1L; 
       public static final Long EDIT = 2L; 
       public static final Long DELETE = 4L; 
       ...
    }
}
```

can be used from within java as `PERMISSION.PAGE.SEE` to retrieve the value `1L`

To achieve a simliar access-possibility from within EL-Expressions, I did this:
(If there is a coding-god - he hopefully might forgive me :D )

```
@Named(value="PERMISSION")
public class PERMISSION{
    public static class PAGE{
       public static final Long SEE = 1L; 
       public static final Long EDIT = 2L; 
       public static final Long DELETE = 4L; 
       ...

       //EL Wrapper
       public Long getSEE(){
           return PAGE.SEE;
       }

       public Long getEDIT(){
           return PAGE.EDIT;
       }

       public Long getDELETE(){
           return PAGE.DELETE;
       }
    }

    //EL-Wrapper
    public PAGE getPAGE() {
        return new PAGE();
    }
}
```

finally, the EL-Expression to access the very same `Long` becomes: `#{PERMISSION.PAGE.SEE}` - equality for Java and EL-Access. I know this is out of any convention, but it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

@Bozho already provided a great answer

> You usually place these kinds of constants in a Configuration object (which has getters and setters) in the servlet context, and access them with ${applicationScope.config.url}

However, I feel an example is needed so it brings a bit more clarity and spare someone's time

```
@Component
public Configuration implements ServletContextAware {
    private String addressURL = Addresses.URL;

    // Declare other properties if you need as also add corresponding
    // getters and setters

    public String getAddressURL() {
        return addressURL;
    }

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setAttribute("config", this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that is not exactly what you want, but lets you active almost the same with touching scriptlets in a quite minimal way. You can use scriptlet to put value into a JSTL variable and use clean JSTL code later in the page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page import="com.whichever.namespace.Addresses" %>
<c:set var="ourUrl" value="<%=Addresses.URL%>"/>
<c:if test='${"http://www.google.com" eq ourUrl}'>
   Google is our URL!
</c:if>
```

Comment: I don't see why this was down-voted. This is the same pattern as option #3 in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16692821/274677