# Calling Java class in JSP

Tags: java, class, jsp

I've done my fair share of research and from what I've seen, I have everything correct. I'm trying to call a Java class in my JSP file. Every time I run it, I get the following error:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 25 in the jsp file: /3680-HW4-Taylor-Jacob/HTML/main.jsp
DateAssistant.formatDate cannot be resolved to a type
22:             out.println("Welcome, " + request.getParameter("usrname") + "!");
23:             
24:             if (timezone.equalsIgnoreCase("United States")){
25:             out.write("You logged in on: " + new DateAssistant.formatDate(gc, timezone) + "

");
26:             
27:             }
28:             out.write("Browse Movies Catalog");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I have the Class file in the correct place (WEB-INF/classes/wu/andy/DateAssistant.class), and I've imported correctly from what I've seen. Here is my JSP source code:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.GregorianCalendar, wu.andy.*" %>
<%
    String interest = request.getParameter("interest");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    int tz = 0;
    String timezone = request.getParameter("country");

    if(password.equals("JTaylor")){
        if(interest.equals("music")){
            response.sendRedirect("music.html");
        } 
        else if(interest.equals("games")){
            response.sendRedirect("games.html");
        } 
        else if(interest.equals("movies")){

            out.write("<html>");
            out.write("<head/>");
            out.write("<body>");
            out.write("<h1 style='color:green'>Movies Galore :: User Main Page</h1>");
            out.println("Welcome, " + request.getParameter("usrname") + "!");

            if (timezone.equalsIgnoreCase("United States")){
            out.write("<p>You logged in on: " + new DateAssistant.formatDate(gc, timezone) + "</p><br/><br/>");

            }
            out.write("<a href='movies.html'>Browse Movies Catalog</a>");


        }
    } else{
        response.sendRedirect("login.html");
    }
%>
```

I know my code is not "good practice" but this is how my professor wants it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference static fields in JSP without using scriptlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270012/reference-static-fields-in-jsp-without-using-scriptlets)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to import DateAssistant class in jsp header.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.GregorianCalendar, wu.andy.*, XXXXX.DateAssistant" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP line:

```
        out.write("<p>You logged in on: " + new DateAssistant.formatDate(gc, timezone) + "</p><br/><br/>");
```

Uses the `new` keyword next to `DateAssistant.formatDate()`. Unless this is a public inner class I think this is a static method in which case you should drop the `new`

Comment: I remove the 'new' keyword and I now get this error: "DateAssistant cannot be resolved."