# Style ENUM in Primefaces datatable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to set the color of a row to red using the dataTable's rowStyleClass attribute. The condition is comparing a enum, so if invoice.status eq InvoiceStatus.CANCELLED, then it should apply the css class 'cancelled' to the row. I think this might not be the proper way to **compare an enum with EL**. Can you tell me how to do it?

```
        <p:dataTable id="invoicesTable" widgetVar="invoicesTable" 
                                        value="#{invoiceManager.invoices}"
                                        var="invoice" 
                                        filteredValue = #{invoiceManager.filteredInvoices}"
                                        paginator="true" 
                                        rows="15" 
                                        paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                        paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                                        emptyMessage="#{msg['warning.noData']}"
           HERE's THE PROBLEM  -->      rowStyleClass="#{invoice.status eq CANCELLED ? 'cancelled' : null}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['title.invoices']}" />
                <p:outputPanel style="position: relative; left: 42%;">
                    <h:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="invoicesTable.filter()" />
                </p:outputPanel>                
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg['label.number']}" filterBy="#{invoice.number}" filterStyle="display: none;">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoice.number}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg['label.customerName']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoice.customer.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="#{msg['label.action']}" styleClass="actionsColumn">
                <p:commandButton process="@this" action="confirmInvoice" icon="ui-icon-search" title="#{msg['button.viewInvoice']}" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{invoiceManager.invoice}" value="#{invoice}" />
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton process="@this" action="#{invoiceManager.changeInvoiceStatus}" icon="ui-icon-flag" title="#{msg['button.changeInvoiceStatus']}" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{invoiceManager.invoice}" value="#{invoice}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: In my opinion, this question doesn't need voting down. I think the question is fair and valid.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl usually people who downvote it have not worked with JSF previously (otherwise they could provide a comment/answer when downvoting).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706726/jsf-2-using-enums-in-the-rendered-attribute

Comment: @SerkanArıkuşu it not a duplicate. Main problem is how to define a row style for some rows and not for entire datatable.

Comment: The question is about using enums in EL and also a best practice; for using the enums it is an duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums are in EL interpreted as strings. You need to quote the enum value.

```
rowStyleClass="#{invoice.status eq 'CANCELLED' ? 'cancelled' : null}"
```

Alternatively, you could add a new method to the enum,

```
public String getStyleClass() {
    return name().toLowerCase();
}
```

and use it as follows

```
rowStyleClass="#{invoice.status.styleClass}"
```

Comment: @BalsusC Cant one just go with the normal java syntax too? E.g `invoice.status eq StatusEnum.Cancelled`

Comment: @Paranaix: No. You can however use a taghandler to import enum constants into EL scope. E.g. OmniFaces `<o:importConstants>`. See also showcase: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants After having declared `<o:importConstants type="com.example.Status"/>`, you could use `#{invoice.status eq Status.CANCELLED ? 'cancelled' : null}`.

Comment: @BalsusC Ah right, some time passed since i dealt with jsf ^^ Rember that i used OmnniFaces  especially for this usecase