# Accessing a field of a Java class directly in EL

Tags: jsp, el, getter

Is there any way to access a field of a Java class using EL if a getter for that field does not exist?

For example, let's say I have a Java class with a field called `foo`.  I know that if I also have a method in the class called `getFoo()` I can do this on a jsp page using this syntax:

```
object.foo
```

However, let's say `getFoo()` does not exist (and I have no way of creating it because I do not have access to the Java class).  How then can I access the `foo` field using EL in my jsp?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el

Comment: Wish I would've found this question BalusC references here when I searched; it answers my question perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to access a field of a Java class using EL if a getter for that field does not exist?

No.  JSP EL is very strict in its requirement for javabean-compliant classes. You need a getter for your field.

Perhaps you can wrap the object in another class that *does* have a getter, and which fetches the field by reflection.

Comment: Yep you can use a Decorator object to decorate the object where you wish to obtain information from. :)

Comment: It's an old answer but I'm still interested in how could this be done?