# Accessing public static final String constants in EL

Tags: jsf, seam, el

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)

I have a Seam JSF application. I have a `Constants.java` class which has

```
public static final String BLAH_STR = "HA_HA";
```

I have to use `BLAH_STR` in EL. `#{Constants.BLAH_STR}` is not working. I have not defined `Constants.java` as a Seam class. How can I solve it?

Comment: Yes. thats correct. Thanks for the link.