# How to use if clause inside a netui data repeater

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, netui, beehive

I'm looking for method to inject value into a `<c:if test>`. The code below works if I substitute

```
<% out.print(request.getSession().getAttribute("UserName").toString()); %>
```

with some constants. But how can I parse a value in `<%%>` tag into a `<c:if test>`?

```
<netui-data:repeater dataSource="pageFlow.availableBooks">
    <tr>
        <td><netui:label value="${container.item.bookName}" /></td>
        <td>
            <c:if test="${container.item.createdBy == '<% out.print(request.getSession().getAttribute("UserName").toString()); %>'}">
            <netui:anchor action="removeBookAction" value="Remove" formSubmit="true">
                <netui:parameter name="bookID" value="${container.item.bookID}" />
            </netui:anchor>
            </c:if>
        </td>
    </tr>
</netui-data:repeater>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessionScope to read the value from session scope.  The following will help you to resolve:

```
<c:if test="${container.item.createdBy == sessionScope.UserName}">
```

Comment: Thanks. but what if it's a static final reference from a class instead of session attribute? for example:

`<% out.println(Books.AUTHOR); %>`

Comment: Its not possible using standard EL. You have to write your own. You may go thru the below URL for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el