# set constant value of java class into hidden field of jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to set the value of constant variable declared in Constants.java class into hidden field of jsp. I don't want to hard code the value 1 into value of hidden field as value can be changed in the future. How can I achieve it?

in Constants.java,

```
public static final int MY_VAR = 1;
```

in JSP,

```
<s:hidden name="myvar" value=""/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference constants in EL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)

Answer (score 1):

You may not use EL here, You can use scriptlet as

`<s:hidden name="myvar" value="<%= Constants.MY_VAR %>"/>`

In this case `s` tag should allow expressions(rtexprvalue should true in its tld configurations). So we should enable `rtexprvalue` to true otherwise we can go with simple HTML as like this

`<input type="hidden" value="<%= Constants.MY_VAR %>"/>`

Comment: I am hitting. org.apache.jasper.JasperException:According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions. I already imported my package in JSP.<%@ page import="pty.com.Constants" %>

Comment: I believe the tag doesn't support JSP expressions.You may verify this by seeing tld for this tag has `rtexprvalue`. You may enable `rtexprvalue` to true to accept expressions. Otherwise use simple HTML as like this `<input type="hidden" value="<%= Constants.MY_VAR %>"/>` instead of `s` tag.

Comment: Yes. when I use simple HTML hidden field, no exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<s:hidden name="myvar" value="<%=Constants.MY_VAR%>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use script let for that. try this-

```
<s:hidden name="myvar"><%=Constants.MY_VAR%></s>
```

Hope that helps!