# Can a class have static/final property in javabean

Tags: jsp, javabeans

Please let me know can we create a property in the class file of javabean as a static or final?

If yes, then is it possible to retrieve the same value from the class and display the value on the screen by using the javabean tag in the jsp file as follows:

```
  <jsp:setProperty/>
  <jsp:getProperty/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just provide a getter for it. A setter (as required by `<jsp:setProperty>`) makes no sense as the variable is apparently supposed to be `final`.

```
private static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "peek-a-boo";

public String getSOME_CONSTANT() {
    return SOME_CONSTANT;
}
```

Other than the old fashioned `<jsp:getProperty>`, you can also just use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (note that this still requires the getter).

```
${bean.SOME_CONSTANT}
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)

Comment: Thanks..so you mean to say we can't use the set() method with static final keyword. Please be more specific with example so that i would be more clear..

Comment: What will be value of having setter method on final?

Comment: Indeed. You can't change the value. The setter method would be completely useless.