# EL 3.0.: Add Constants from Class to ELContext with spring managed bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf, el, jsf-2.2

I try to make contants working for my web-application using JSF 2.2., EL 3.0..

Regarding to this post [in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3735006/799526) it is possible to do this with EL 3.0. like that:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Config {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().addELContextListener(new ELContextListener() {
          @Override
          public void contextCreated(ELContextEvent event) {  
             event.getELContext().getImportHandler().importClass("com.example.YourConstants");
         }
       });
    }
}
```

Are there any examples how to get that to work if the beans are not managed by jsf?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Omnifaces importConstants. It should do all the work for you.

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants

Taken from the omnifaces example...

Managed Bean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import org.omnifaces.showcase.model.ExampleEnum;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ConstantsBean {

    public static final String CONSTANT1 = "Constant one";
    public static final String CONSTANT2 = "Constant two";

    private ExampleEnum exampleEnum;

    public ExampleEnum getExampleEnum() {
        return exampleEnum;
    }

    public void setExampleEnum(ExampleEnum exampleEnum) {
        this.exampleEnum = exampleEnum;
    }

}
```

ExampleEnum

```
public enum ExampleEnum {

    ONE, TWO, THREE;

    public String getFriendlyName() {
        return name().charAt(0) + name().substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

Sample usage in XHTML

```
<o:importConstants type="org.omnifaces.showcase.taghandlers.ConstantsBean" />
<o:importConstants type="org.omnifaces.showcase.model.ExampleEnum" />

<h3>All constants of <code>ConstantsBean</code></h3>
<ul>
    <li>#{ConstantsBean.CONSTANT1}</li>
    <li>#{ConstantsBean.CONSTANT2}</li>
</ul>

<hr />

<h3>All values of <code>ExampleEnum</code></h3>
<ul>
    <li>#{ExampleEnum.ONE}</li>
    <li>#{ExampleEnum.TWO}</li>
    <li>#{ExampleEnum.THREE}</li>
</ul>
```