# How to configure taglibs unstandard-1.0 in JSF 2.2 page?

Tags: maven-2, constants, el, taglib, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use my constants in jsf page.

I installed the library with maven thanks to a remote repository in pom.xml as explain here.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)
[How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)

My header is like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"   
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"  
    xmlns:un="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/unstandard-1.0" >
```

Eclipse send me this error.

```
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

I tried to put taglib.tld in WEB-INF without sucess...
What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: if your problem is related to custom validation messages, then you can put `validation.properties` file in `src` and add in `faces-config.xml` path to this file: `<application>
    <message-bundle>your.path.here.resource.validation</message-bundle>
 </application>`

Comment: yeah i know but that's not the problem...i finally choose to use Omnnifaces.that resolved the prob.thanks