# JSP access to non jdk provided static fields/methods (JSP EL 3.0)

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, el, tomcat8

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768377/access-static-property-or-method-in-jsp-via-el-3-0-jee7-tomcat-8), I learned how to provide my JSP (running on Tomcat 8.0.9) access to static fields and methods of java.lang classes or even, for example, classes in the `java.time` package using code like this:

```
package test;

import javax.el.ELContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory;

@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {
  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getJspApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()).addELContextListener((ELContextEvent e) -> {
      e.getELContext().getImportHandler().importPackage("java.time");
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {}
}
```

And now I can do: `${LocalDate.now{}}` from within my JSP.  However, when I attempt to import my own class into the el context:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
  JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getJspApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()).addELContextListener((ELContextEvent e) -> {
    e.getELContext().getImportHandler().importPackage("java.time");
    e.getELContext().getImportHandler().importClass("test.LocalDateUtils");
  });
}
```

Given the test.LocalDateUtils class:

```
package test;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public final class LocalDateUtils {

  public static boolean isToday(LocalDate date) {
    return LocalDate.now().equals(date);
  }
}
```

When invoked from the JSP using:

```
${LocalDateUtils.isToday(LocalDate.now())}
```

I run into the exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: The class [test.LocalDateUtils] could not be imported as it could not be found
javax.el.ImportHandler.importClass(ImportHandler.java:114)
```

How do I add my custom classes into the ImportHandler's classpath so that they can be found and resolved?