# Accessing JSTL <c:forEach> varStatus in JSP Expression

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a JSP that imports an interface. The interface has a `String[] QUESTION_ARRAY`.

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page import="com.mypackage.message.Questions"%>

<table>
    <c:forEach var="question" items="<%=Questions.QUESTION_ARRAY%>" varStatus="ctr">
        <tr>
            <td><%=Questions.QUESTION_ARRAY[ctr.index]%></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

In `[ctr.index]`, it is saying `ctr` is unresolved. How do I access it inside the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `ctr` created in the page scope. To access page scope variable in JSP expression you can use `pageContext` implicit object.

```jsp
<table>
  <% pageContext.setAttribute("questions", Questions.QUESTION_ARRAY); %>
  <c:forEach var="question" items="${questions}" varStatus="ctr">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%=Questions.QUESTION_ARRAY[((LoopTagStatus)pageContext.getAttribute("ctr")).getIndex()]%>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

But it seems ugly if you are using it with JSTL `forEach` tag. Better to construct the JSP EL expression.

```jsp
<table>
  <% pageContext.setAttribute("questions", new Questions(){}.QUESTION_ARRAY); %>
  <c:forEach var="question" items="${questions}" varStatus="ctr">
    <tr>
      <td>
        ${questions[ctr.index]} 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Even this expression not necessary if you are using `var` attribute of the `forEach` tag which defines the variable referencing the element of the array, also in the page scope. You can access it like

```jsp
<table>
  <% pageContext.setAttribute("questions", Questions.QUESTION_ARRAY); %>
  <c:forEach var="question" items="${questions}" >
    <tr>
      <td>
        ${question}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Also see this question for other alternatives:
[How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)

Comment: Despite our previous misunderstanding, I'm upvoting and accepting this answer, because it worked. Particularly, a combination of the 2nd and 3rd code snippets. Thanks for showing how to access the `ctr`, I needed that for something I wasn't able to mention in the original question.

Comment: I appreciate things that you understand the style of communication on SO, I'm happy that it was helpful to you and may be others.

Comment: do you think setting attributes in the JSP itself violates MVC2?

Comment: not really from the view layer you can communicate to the model.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the index if you are already iterating the questions? Why do you use JSTL for the loop and scriptlets for the output?

If I understand your scenario correctly, this should look something like the below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<bean:define id="questions" type="ph.edu.iacademy.message.Questions" />

<table>
    <c:forEach var="question" items="questions.QUESTION_ARRAY" >
        <tr>
            <td>${question.text}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

If you really do want access to the status then you can do it as:

```
${ctr.index}
```

Comment: Is there any other uri that needs to be included? `<bean:define>` is saying "unknown tag".