# Import data from databean to trigger enable/disable on checkbox (jsp/html)

Tags: java, html, jsp

on a jsp file I have the following code that is used by the page to populate the DataBean java class with some data:

```
<jsp:useBean id="dataBean" scope="request" class="a.b.c.DataBean"/>
```

The DataBean.java has the method:

```
public static String getOverrideOption() {
    return OVERRIDE_OPTION;
}
```

I want to use that method on the page to enable/disable a checkbox depending on the return, this is the code on the jsp:

```
<tr>
    <th class="light">Use old method:</th>
    <td colspan="2">
        <span class="radiobuttons">
            <input type="checkbox" alt="Old Method" name="oldMethod"
                ${dataBean.oldMethod ? "checked" : ""} />
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried creating a script to try and fetch the data, assign it to a variable or string and then make the string as enabled/disabled on the checkbox but so far no success.

I am not very familiar with jsp so I am trying to figure it out but no luck so far, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited:***

Try removing static modifier,

```
${'your string' == dataBean.getOverrideOption() ? "checked" : ""}
```

Comment: Won't work, it is not possible to access static variables/methods from JSP EL. There are some workarounds, though, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el

Comment: I can make the method not static without impact to the application code, which I will do in a bit and try it again