# How to properly decode cookie values in a JSP using EL?

Tags: jsp, curl, el, tomcat8

I want to display the value of a cookie on a JSP page. Using EL, I crafted this:

```
<c:set var="errorFlash" value="${cookie['error']}"/>
<c:if test="${null != errorFlash}">
    <p>${fn:escapeXml(errorFlash.value)}</p>
</c:if>
```

This seems to work, but I am not sure if this would decode special URL characters in the cookie value correctly. I did a quick test using curl like this:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/login -v -b 'error=Hello%20World'
[...]
> Cookie: error=Hello%20World
[...]
<p>Hello%20World</p>
[...]
```

So it does not seem to decode the %20 character sequence correctly. However, this might be an issue with curl, not with my Tomcat instance. Here's another take:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/login -v -b 'error=Hello World'
[...]
> Cookie: error=Hello World
[...]
<p>Hello</p>
[...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a custom tag lib which decodes the data, or either (bad-way) a simple scriplet which decodes the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`${fn:escapeXml()}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) escapes [predefined XML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML). It does not have any associations with [URL encoding nor decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). See also [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application).

Provided that you're on EL 3.0 (Tomcat 8 supports it), then you can use [`ELContext#getImportHandler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELContext.html#getImportHandler--) to import [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ImportHandler.html#importPackage-java.lang.String-), [classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ImportHandler.html#importClass-java.lang.String-) and [constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ImportHandler.html#importStatic-java.lang.String-) into EL scope. You can make use of it to import the [`java.net.URLDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class which contains the [`decode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method you need.

Put this somewhere in top of your JSP:

```
${pageContext.ELContext.importHandler.importClass('java.net.URLDecoder')}
```

Then you can decode the cookie as below:

```
<c:if test="${not empty cookie.error}">
    <p>${URLDecoder.decode(cookie.error.value, 'UTF-8')}</p>
</c:if>
```

True, that EL expression to import the class reminds in a scary way of legacy *Scriptlets*. Fortunately, you can configure this globally with help of a `ServletContextListener` like below:

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getJspApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()).addELContextListener(new ELContextListener() {
            @Override
            public void contextCreated(ELContextEvent event) {
                event.getELContext().getImportHandler().importClass("java.net.URLDecoder");
            }
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)
- [Slide from Reza Rahman about what's new in Java EE 7's EL 3.0](http://www.slideshare.net/reza_rahman/whats-new-with-expression-language-in-java-ee-7)
- [Java EE 7 tutorial - Chapter 9: EL 3.0](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm#GJDDD)