# Java EE 7 + EL 3.0 + Wildfly 10 - returns empty string on constant

Tags: eclipse, jsp, constants, el, wildfly-10

According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el), it should be possible to retrieve the value of a constant by using Expression Language 3.0

According to [this article](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Getting+Started+Guide), Wildfly 10 has implemented Java EE 7 and EL 3.0

However, when I create a new Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse with a new empty JSP file with two constant references and deploy it to Wildfly 10, the variables are presented as empty (or non-existing).

This is the example JSP page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        2 + 2 = ${2 + 2}<br>
        ContextPath: ${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}<br>
        Boolean.TRUE: ---${Boolean.TRUE}---<br>
        Integer.MAX_VALUE: ---${Integer.MAX_VALUE}---<br>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the result in the browser.

```
2 + 2 = 4
ContextPath: /helloworld
Boolean.TRUE: ------
Integer.MAX_VALUE: ------
```

What is the reason that these variables are returned empty?

Comment: Just an FYI, I tried this out on WebSphere Application Server V9 which supports EL 3.0 and it works.  The output in question in my browser shows:
'Boolean.TRUE: ---true---
Integer.MAX_VALUE: ---2147483647---'  Therefore this could be an issue specific to Wildfly

Comment: Note that the answer you found already mentions that some (early) servers have bugs on this. I had at the time of writing not tested WF10 on this, but I recall having tested WF8. Can you try 10.1 beta? If it also fails there, report it to WF guys  as soon as you can.

Comment: WF10.1-CR1 shows the same behavior. By now, a bug report has been created: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6939

Comment: A patch has been created and is readied for Widlfly 10.1.0-Final, see https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/commit/d1212ed7091627aed9696d2e5361bdf30b39e9af

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the variables are returned empty is because Wildfly 10.0 contains two bugs which result in that behavior:

1. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6939
2. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6943

The issue has been fixed in Wildfly 10.1, which has been released:

- http://wildfly.org/news/2016/08/19/WildFly10-1-Released

Wildfly 10.1.0 Final can be downloaded here:

- http://wildfly.org/downloads