# Ways to use local variable in another class ( showing it in jsp page)

Tags: java, jsp

Is there a way to get values of local variables in one class and show that in jsp page?

For example,

```
public class a { 
    public method b() { 
         String c;
```

I want to use the String c and show it in jsp page.

```
${c}
```

**1)** Is there a way to use a local variable of a class from outside of that class?
**2)** if not, just make the variable global, and use it?  ( What I mean by global is using static. I looked it up and Java doesn't have global variable)
**3)** if so, in JSP page, can you tell me some ways to show that value?

> ${class.variable name} <--- Would this work as well?

Comment: 1) No. A **local** variable is not visible from outside the block where it is defined.

2) + 3) Theoretically, [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el). Anyway, I would not recommend this unless you really know what you are doing, which seems - no offence - not to be your case.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek   okay~ thank you for your advice!  Maybe, you can put this as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Why using a global variable ? You can just use a class member to hold `c` and use a getter... or simply return `c` from the method.

Comment: @AxelH  I was just curious. :)  I want to know many ways if exists.

Comment: @AxelH  When you return C from the method,   I just call that method from other class? ( after importing the class of the method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No. A **local** variable is not visible from outside the block where it is defined.

2) + 3) Theoretically, [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el). Anyway, I would not recommend this unless you really know what you are doing. Solutions like the one in the link should be very exceptional, because they go against the best practices.