# How to get the value in an EnumMap using a key in EL expression?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have a EnumMap:

```
EnumMap<Gender, Integer> genderMap = new EnumMap(Gender.class);
```

where Gender is  `public enum Gender {Male, Female};`

And I have `req.setAttribute("genderMap", genderMap);`

Now I want to get the value from `genderMap` by a key in JSP file:

```
${genderMap['Male']}
```

but this doesn't get the value in `genderMap`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use enum mappings. Just use enums as enums in Java and as strings in JSP/EL.

I'll assume that you need that integer because of a database mapping. E.g. `Male` is stored as `1` in database and `Female` is stored as `0` in database. In that case, you need to redesign your enum as follows:

```
public enum Gender {

    Male(1), Female(0);

    private int id;

    private Gender(int id) { 
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static Gender valueOf(int id) {
        for (Gender gender : values()) {
            if (gender.id == id) {
                return gender;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

When populating the `Person` from DB by JDBC, just do

```
person.setGender(Gender.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("gender")));
```

When showing preselected options to enduser in JSP, just do

```
request.setAttribute("genders", Gender.values());
```

and

```xml
Gender:<br/>
<c:forEach items="${genders}" var="gender">
    <input type="radio" id="gender_${gender.id}" name="gender" value="${gender.id}" 
        ${gender == person.gender ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
    <label for="gender_${gender.id}">${gender}</label>
    <br />
</c:forEach>
```

or even without the `id`

```xml
Gender:<br/>
<c:forEach items="${genders}" var="gender">
    <input type="radio" id="gender_${gender}" name="gender" value="${gender}" 
        ${gender == person.gender ? 'checked="checked"' : ''} />
    <label for="gender_${gender}">${gender}</label>
    <br />
</c:forEach>
```

When collecting submitted values in servlet, just do

```
Gender gender = Gender.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("gender")));
```

or when using without `id` in HTML

```
Gender gender = Gender.valueOf(request.getParameter("gender"));
```

Comment: OK, thx for the answer. My solution is Using a new Map: HashMap<String, Integer> genderMap, where Key(String) is Gender.name(). So I can use genderMap['Male'] to get the value in jsp.

Comment: Hate to downvote, but the answer doesnt really address the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Gender, Integer> genderMap = new HashMap<Gender, Integer>();
```

and

`${genderMap['Male']}`

this would work definitely.

Comment: Err, no. HashMap is not a subclass of EnumMap, and 'Male' evaluates to a String, not a Gender.

Comment: `Male` would evaluted to ENUM , See :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123598/access-enum-value-using-el-with-jstl

Comment: No. In the top answer of the question you linked to, the solution consists in comparing strings together. someModel.status is converted to a string and compared to the string 'OLD'. And my point regarding HashMap and EnumMap still stands.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<Gender, Integer> to EnumMap<Gender, Integer>

Answer (score 0):

Because `'Male'` evaluates to the String "Male", not to `Gender.Male`. You would need to have access to the `Gender.Male` constant to access its map entry. But accessing constants is not possible in JSP EL, so you might want to do :

```
req.setAttribute("male", Gender.Male);
req.setAttribute("genderMap", genderMap);

...

${genderMap[male]}
```

Comment: What if the enum 'Gender' has a hundred values, do I have to "req.setAttribute("some enum value" Gender.someValue)" a hundred time?

Comment: You could put all these values in a single bean, or you could step back a little and ask yourself if accessing hundreds of specific values in a JSP is normal, and shouldn't be encapsulated somehow in some piece of Java code.

Comment: As to setting it hundred times, you have the same problem when using a `Map`. You would call `put()` hundred times as well.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a wrapper (adapter) for enum maps. It expects String keys and converts them to corresponding Enum values by calling Enum.valueOf() method.

Relevant parts from an example bean:

```
private Map <Action, Permission> permissions = new EnumMap<>(Action.class);

/** For java access */
public Map<Action, Permission> getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
}

/** For EL access */
public Map<String, Permission> getPermissionsAsString() {
    return new EnumMapWrapper<>(Action.class, permissions);
}
```

Now I can conveniently access the map elements in EL:

```
#{rule.permissionsAsString['MODIFY']}
```

Here's the wrapper class:

```
public class EnumMapWrapper<K extends String, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private Map<Enum, V> map;
    private Class<? extends Enum> enumType;

    public EnumMapWrapper(Class<? extends Enum> enumType, Map<? extends Enum, V> map) {
        this.enumType = enumType;
        this.map = (Map<Enum, V>)map;
    }

    private Enum valueOf(Object key) {
        if (!(key instanceof String)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only string keys are permitted");
        }

        return Enum.valueOf(enumType, (String)key);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return map.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return map.containsKey(valueOf(key));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return map.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return map.get(valueOf(key));
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return map.put(valueOf(key), value);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        return map.remove(valueOf(key));
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return map.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```