# Access enum from jstl

Tags: java, spring, jsp, enums, jstl

I am trying access `Enum` options from `jstl`:

```
<select name="user_role">
    <spring:eval expression="UserRole.Role.values()" var="_enum"/>
    <c:forEach items="${_enum}" var="role">

        <option value="${role}">${role}</option>

    </c:forEach>

</select>
```

I see empty selector at run-time and my IDE warning me that 
`Namespace 'spring' is not bound` on my `jsp`.

**Question:**
Is it possible to access `enum` from `jstl`? How to fix my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123598/access-enum-value-using-el-with-jstl